# I want To share Multiple Picture With Single Caption

Tags: android, android-intent, share, whatsapp

I want to share multiple picture with single caption which is shown on one image not on all of them. But caption will show on every pic which is shared at one time.

Here is my code

```
private void pic_with_data() {

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(); 
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUriArray);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Download this App");
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");

    shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image!"));
        startActivity(shareIntent);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Whatsapp have not been installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by **Single Caption Which is show on One Image Not on all. But Caption will show on Every Pic**  ??

Comment: Hi Mohit..I mean when I share multiple picture to whatsapp,but text will be same in every pic.And I want  share text only on single Image Not on every Image

Comment: **text will be same in every pic** for this i would suggest to create bitmap with text on it and put all image in array list share list

Comment: Mohit, Please share some method for this

Comment: i can share you method.. but the process i am referring will print text on image and then will converted into bitmap which will not be changed after created (like bookmark) , but i can see you are sending **Download this app** message with every image which is manually entered

Comment: i want to sending( Download this app message) with One image  Not every Image

Comment: ok... but in process you wont be sending it with any image, not even with  one...instead  you create image with text placed on it and share all as list

Comment: I told you, it is like watermark (sorry for bad english, like watermark not bookmark)

Comment: did you find solution ?

Comment: Not at All...  :(

Comment: So will watermark solution work for you ??

Comment: No because watermark is not clickable i want to add link below image so user click on link and go to playstore. Watermark is not a solution for this.

Comment: ok ... then you have to share all image manually with text as a list.. may be below solution work for you

Comment: @SahilChoudhary  Hi, Did you get anything related to your question. Don't want watermark. Just wanted to share one text and multiple images with code ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` instead of `Intent.ACTION_SEND`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Here are some files.");
intent.setType("image/jpeg"); /* This example is sharing jpeg images. */

ArrayList<Uri> files = new ArrayList<Uri>();

for(String path : filesToSend /* List of the files you want to send */) {
    File file = new File(path);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    files.add(uri);
}

intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, files);
startActivity(intent);
```

Remember, Starting in API 24, sharing file URIs will cause a FileUriExposedException. To remedy this, you can either switch your compileSdkVersion to 23 or lower or you can use content URIs with a [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing).

Comment: but still text is shown below every image  this is annoying. i want to share only text below first image not others.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't had a chance to compile this but this should work

```
val files: ArrayList<Uri> = arrayListOf()
    // add files here in `files` variable

    startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        .setType("image/*")
        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
        .putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, files))
```

Comment: This did not work.