# How to share multiple images with single caption in whatsapp?

Tags: android, arraylist, whatsapp

I want to share image array via `Whatsapp` with text , but there is a  text which always send with every image.
I try many way but nothing works.

```
try {

     Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
     shareIntent.setType("text/html");
     shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) getUri(bitmapList));
     shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "farm");
     shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"image");

     context.startActivity(shareIntent);
 }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

**Right now I get output as below**:

[image: image with seperate text]
**What I want my output as below:**

[image: image with single text]

Comment: check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661875/how-to-use-share-image-using-sharing-intent-to-share-images-in-android?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @AndroidUser I want to send image with text. please read my question.

Comment: It maybe Possible Whats App does not accept `Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` .. DO you see WhatsApp in Sharing Dialog as an option ?

Comment: @ADM Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE is working fine. but problem is it send EXTRA_TEXT to each image .

Comment: That is not possible  ..`EXTRA_TEXT` will accept single String as message .

Comment: @ADM kindly refer my update to question . I put images to understand

Comment: Either you set `EXTRA_TEXT` or you send it blank for one request .. I think this is also not possible. Its the way WhatsApp is handling the `Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` and you can not modify it.Caption with each image .. [This thread discussing the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51839604/i-want-to-share-multiple-picture-with-single-caption) with no Solution ..

Comment: @PriyankaC Its amazing how people lack reading comprehension skills, in spite of giving clear example with pictures, developers dont take time to read carefully. ADM No sir it is possible, I have seen many other apps sharing images with whatsapp using caption for the first image only. I still have not found the fix but it is possible.